# How to get the size of string array dynamically?

Tags: c++

How can I get the size of a string array dynamically?
For example:

```
string names[5] = {"John","Smith","Noob"};
```

And somehow I should get the size which is 2

How can I do that? without using vectors or loop?

Comment: 2? Are you sure?

Comment: Could you explain your definition of size? How do you get `2`?

Comment: @pmr Silly, "Noob" is not a name!

Comment: No, the size of the array is still 5, just some items are default-initialized.

Comment: the index starts from 0 and it's 0=John,Smith=1,Noob=2 :-?

Comment: The array size is 5. You've initialized the first three with custom strings, and the remaining two have been default initialized. You'll need to track this yourself.

Comment: The size of the array is `5 * sizeof(string)`, the number of elements in the array is `5`.

Comment: Will `(sizeof names)/(sizeof names[0])` return the size of the array? (number of elements in it?)

Comment: use a `std::vector<std::string>`. There is no real elegant simple way to do what your asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array size is still five.

The elements that you didn't provide values for are default-initialised, i.e. `""`. But they're still *there* and everything.

Comment: are you sure the default-initialized values are not nulls?

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, I am. There is no such thing as a "null" `std::string`.

Comment: @Vlad `std::string`s cannot be null.

Comment: Oh, didn't see strings there. I was confused by `""`, which should perhaps better be `string()`.

Comment: Ok so what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: @Johnnie: you can't, there's no way.

Comment: @Vlad: `[C++11: 8.5.1/7]`. You're right about `std::string()` being more precise, though I think `""` probably makes more sense to the OP in this case.

Comment: so , I need to loop till the end?

Comment: @Johnnie: Why do you need to do anything at all?

Comment: I need to get the number of elements initialized from the string array then loop through all elemements and convert them intro char array

Comment: @Johnnie: And why's that? Tell us your goal, not your proposed solution for that goal.

Comment: as I said I need to know how many elements are initialized to know how many strings I transform into char array

Comment: @Johnnie: You're just repeating yourself now, which is not helpful.

Comment: @Johnnie There's no way to create an array without initialising all the elements. The solution is either keep track of the number yourself, or, better, use std::vector which will keep track of the number for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer the question, getting the size of array is as follows:

```
int arr[17];
int arrSize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
```

But yes, in your case, it's init'd as 5, so it's 5.

Comment: Better write `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t array_size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }` and use that. The `sizeof` technique is prone to un-diagnosed mistakes when you got the "array" as a function argument (no you didn't).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it looks like we all have that `array_size` function stashed away somewhere :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: In my brain sah!

Comment: Hmm I wonder whether that can be `constexpr`d nowadays

Comment: With C++ a good way to get the array size is to write `end(a)-begin(a)`, using `std::begin` and `std::end` from `<utility>`. This expression also works for a standard container such as a `std::vector`. With C++03 use the technique exemplified by Lightness Races in Orbit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of the array to be determined by the number of initializers you can do this:

```
string names[] = {"John","Smith","Noob"};
```

`string name[]` is an incomplete array type, and the language figures out the correct size necessary to complete it from the initializer. The size of the array will be 3 in this case.

Raw arrays aren't very friendly though, and so if possible you might want to avoid them and, in this case, use a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> names {"John","Smith","Noob"};
```

Although your compiler will need to support C++11 to use this method of initializing vectors.

---

> I need to get the number of elements initialized from the string array then loop through all elemements and convert them intro char array

Why not just start with char* in the first place then?

```
char const *names[] = {"John","Smith","Noob"};
```